# Issue with range in swagger allowableValues

Tags: spring-mvc, range, swagger

Following is a piece of code which I cam across for the usage of allowableValues in @ApiParam :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/operations/parameters/allowableRange/{id}"}, method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String allowableRange(
@ApiParam(defaultValue = "1", allowableValues = "range[1, 99]")
@PathVariable Integer id) {
return "";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/operations/parameters/allowableValues/{id}"}, method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String allowableValues(
@ApiParam(defaultValue = "1", allowableValues = "1,2,3,4,5")
@PathVariable Integer id) {
return "";
}
```

I tried out the same and the part where we provide a range does not work, I am even able to give id as 1000(range is 1-99) and it still works .My swagger version is 0.8.8. Anything that i'm missing?

Comment: Are you talking about the swagger-ui not respecting the fact that you specified the range and the ui is not restricting the input to your specified range?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue

Answer (score 1):

Swagger is just a tool for API documentation, so technically it does nothing.